# How to use sed to replace directory name

Tags: sed

In a file a.py I have multiple lines which look like this:

```
with open('./260/U') as infile, open('./260/Uout', 'w') as outfile:
```

I am trying to search and replace all of the /260/ directories with $dir using sed:

```
dir=200
sed -i 's+\/.*?\/+\/'"$dir"'\/+g' "./a.py"
```

However my attempt does not modify the file. How do I replace all of the /xxxx/ (i.e an unknown string between two slashes, in this case /260/) with /$dir/?

Comment: Sed doesn't support the `.*?` non greedy match, and you don't need to escape `/` since you're using `+` as the delimiter. So try `'s+/[^/]*/+/'"$dir"'/+g'`

Comment: In general, I suggest you to use the `os` [python module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) and have readable, customizable code, and modify the path whenever you want without any sed.